# Strong json desktop editor

Tags: xml, json

I am looking for a strong json desktop editor.
I want it to be able to:

1. open 40000 rows files.
2. indent json
3. present as a tree - expand / collapse
4. evaluate JsonPath
5. have jsonpath console.
6. Bulk operation on jsonpath.

(All these features are present in Altova's xml spy - but they are better implemented on xml, not json.)

Comment: Did you find this tool? Can I talk to you about this? I'm thinking of building a similar tool.

Comment: Maybe email the author of that good XML tool and suggets a JSON version?

Comment: hi, @PavelChuchuva did you ever code such a tool?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean with bulk operations on JSON path but doesn't provide [JSONBuddy](http://json-buddy.com) all of this?

Comment: I believe that it does. Current cost is $29. [Here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69065/gratis-windows-alternative-to-jsonbuddy) is my question asking for a gratis alternative