# Gratis Windows alternative to JSONbuddy

Tags: windows, gratis, json

There's are a bunch of JSON viewers, editors, validators, exported, importers, converters out there, but I am looking for a gratis alternative to [JSONbuddy](https://www.json-buddy.com/).

Deal make/break must have feature is a visually nested representation such as this

[image]

Other good features that it has are CSV import/export, convert to/from XML, schema & JSON validation.

Does anyone know of a gratis alternative for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSONedit](https://tomeko.net/software/JSONedit) might be similar:
[image: JSONedit]

From features you have listed:

- there is only CSV import with few mapping templates, no export
- no XML conversion
- no schema support (which draft version are you using?)

Comment: http://tomeko.net/software/JSONedit/ -> http://tomeko.net/software/JSONedit/bin/JSONedit_0_9_32_2.zip or if you really would need UTF-8 -> http://tomeko.net/software/JSONedit/bin/JSONedit_0_10_0_1.zip (0.9.x has more features and ANSI character subset is often enough)